# Displaying the first child page of the parent page

Tags: child-pages

```
Rooms
  Rooms 1
  Rooms 2
  Rooms 3
  Rooms 4
```

Rooms is the parent page and I want to display only the first child page.

Currently, I am using the code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 4,
    'title_li' => '',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date'
 );

 $pages = wp_list_pages($args);
```

It is fetching all the child pages. I am new to Wordpress coding and so need help.

Comment: The problem is that "first" needs a "order". So, first by what? By name? By ID? By date? Just first of whatever?

Comment: First of whatever. For the question's sake, please assume Room 1 as first child page. u can take first by creation date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) with a limit of 1:

```
$pages = get_pages([
    'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
    'number'   => 1,
]);

if ( $pages ) {
    $first_page = current( $pages );
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"